# navigation drawer error with splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, navigation-drawer

navigation drawer is working perfect also splash screen code is working perfect in other app but when i add splash screen code to this navigation drawer the app won't open
i tried all different methods but no luck it always display an error and wont open at all an no reference on the internet

```
package com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
  private CharSequence mTitle;
  CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;
  private ImageView splashImageView;
  boolean splashloading = false;
  List<DrawerItem> dataList;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        splashImageView = new ImageView(this);
        splashImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        splashImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setContentView(splashImageView);
        splashloading = true;
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                splashloading = false;
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

        }, 3000);


        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                    GravityCompat.START);

        // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",
                    R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                    dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {
              public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                              // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
              }

              public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                              // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
              }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
              SelectItem(0);
        }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
  }

  public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {
        case 0:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 1:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 2:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 3:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 4:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 5:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 6:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 7:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 8:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 9:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 10:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 11:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 12:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        default:
              break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

  }

  @Override
  public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
              return true;
        }

        return false;
  }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
              ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
              SelectItem(position);

        }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making **separate** Activities for your SplashScreen and MainActivity.

Here's how -

> - Make two Activities, `SplashScreenActivity` and `MainActivity`
> - Mark SplashScreenActivity as your as MAIN LAUNCHER activity in manifest.
> - When your Splash Screen timer ends, start your MainActivity using `startActivity()`

Since both your activities are working independently, this solution is very likely to work.

Hope it helps.